# Iframe anchor doesnt work

Tags: iframe, frameset-iframe

I have a form inside an iframe. On submit, it loads a thank you page. I need to scroll to the top of the iframe on submit.

I tried using #anchor but because my iframe is inside of a blogger post, it doesn't work.

here is my page
http://www.moscdc.org/2013/09/membership-form.html

thank you